# Highly variable elements?

Tags: genomics

Which type of genomic elements in the UCSC browser can be used as an example of the highly labile = highly variable = low conservation regions?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have any requirements of the length of such elements? Are SNP ok or should it be longer? Do you want to include mobile sections of the genome or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transposable elements (TEs) are the classic example of rapidly evolving regions in eukaryotic genomes. These are often used as a proxy for neutrally evolving sequences, which are by definition not conserved/constrained. The UCSC genome browser includes various repeat tracks (e.g. RepeatMasker) that includes TEs.

Within protein coding regions, 4-fold degenerate sites are often used as a proxy for neutrally evolving sequences. These sites are where any nucleotide at this position leads to the same amino acid and therefore protein (synonymous mutations).

Potentially even more variable sequences would be those under positive selection, but there is not a single class of element that falls into this category i think.

Comment: Thanks! A very helpful answer!

Comment: @MaxRempel You can upvote the answer (by clicking on the up arrow on the left of it) if you consider it useful. Since you are the original poster of the question, you may even  mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue in a satisfactory manner.

Comment: I think using TEs  as proxies for neutrally evolving sequences is a bit bold. TEs have functional portions, which are very likely under evolutionary constraints.

Comment: @bli of course some TEs have functions, but as a whole group, they remain a widely used proxy for neutrally evolving sequences in many studies

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense! I received a similar answer from another expert.